# Are there any JavaScript events being fired when swiping on the WebView with Talkback (screen reader) is on?

Tags: accessibility, talkback

I have an Android app that hosts an WebView and we want to adopt some accessibility feature on it.

Short question:
Are there any talkback events on the JavaScript side being fired when user swipe left or right on the WebView?

Details:
On the WebView I have a [carousel component](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) displaying some images. **I want to do some specific actions**, in the accessibility mode, when users do a single-fingle-swipe left or right (in this case, a single-fingle-swipe means ***going to next / previous available element***). So in this way, if there are any events being fired that I can catch, it would be great.

---

Edited the question with a [image that explains in details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dJb1.jpg).

Thanks!

Comment: This is super broad, and the answer doesn't really involve code in any way. The answer to this would be a blog post about the relationship between the browser and the native accessibility layer. And while this information is useful, StackOverflow is not the place for it. Try asking a more concise question.

Comment: @ChrisCM Hi Chris. Thanks for your response. I drew [a little diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dJb1.jpg) to demonstrate the problem in a concise way. Hope it helps!

Comment: On the android side, it would be possible if we launch an AccessibilityService running and detect the scroll action. But I think it might be a little heavy and CPU-intensive.

Comment: It's not the question that is not concise, it is the answer. Your question is very consumable and has a very clear answer. But any helpful answer is essentially a tutorial on the relationship between Javascript, Chrome, and the Native Android Accessibility layer. Cool info, but not anything I plan on typing up on StackOverflow, it's just not where that type of answer belongs. I have a series of blog posts and videos you can check out, I don't want to advertise them here, reach out to me on LinkedIn.